# Javascript - can I get url of child window?

Tags: javascript

I need such functional - get URL of child window after it loaded

```
var ref = window.open(link, window_params);  // link - external in other domain
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(ref.location.href);
}, 1000); // 100 ms for example
```

I get error

```
 Error: Permission denied to access property 'href'
```

I know about origin restriction to get url from window in another origin and read FAQ after this article - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.open

Can i get url of opened window in some way? Any ideas?

Comment: if it's not your script that is opening the window, you should be able to just find the script that opens the window, in turn, find the href of the window that is opening.

Comment: It is my script that open window. But in this window - external site with Oauth authorization

Comment: what is `link` in `window.open(link, window_params)`

Comment: This is not important. Domain is not same

link = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id='+this.app_id+'&scope='+this.permissions+'&redirect_uri=http://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=touch&response_type=token';

Comment: for what you are trying to accomplish - i don't think it's possible.  javascript can't operate within another window. my recommendation would be ajax if that's an option

Comment: User must type your login and password and this window. Using ajax is impossible. But thanks for your ideas.

Comment: @VladimirCherepinskiy Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: @kennethkoontz No, i think its impossible in normal mode of browser. I can access to this params only if load browser with disabled web secutiry.

Answer (score 0):

If the opened page is within your control, you should be able to set up a callback function in the parent which the child window calls;

**Parent**

```
window.OnChildWindowLoaded = function (href) {
    console.log('Opened ' + href + ' successfully');
};
window.open('Child.html', ...);
```

**Child.html**

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    window.opener.OnChildWindowLoaded(location.href);
};
</script>
```

Comment: It works only on same origin and I haven`t control on child.html

Comment: @VladimirCherepinskiy I also have the same problem. Could you find a solution?

Comment: @Dinesh - Unfortunately - No. I think thi is impossible due origin restriction